# Use Dell 4700C as remote backup machine

Tags: backup, bios, wake-on-lan

I have an old Dell 4700C that I would like to put out in my shop to use to backup the hard drive for the machine in my house.  I don't really want this thing running all the time, only when I want to actually run the backup.  I was hoping to use WOL to turn the PC remotely, run the backup and then shut it down.
The 4700C has 'Remote Wake Up', but per [documentation](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim4700/sm/syssetup.htm#wp1052321):

> The computer can be powered up remotely from the suspend or standby
>   modes only.

I'm running Windows 7 in my house and and can run Windows XP or Ubuntu on the 4700c.  My budget is limited, so I'm trying to make the hardware I currently have work.

I really do not want to leave this PC running even in standby.  Is there anyway to get around the motherboard's requirement to have the computer in a suspended state and have it be off until I tell it to wake up?

(@Keltari has recommended I check into a BIOS update, which I haven't been able to do yet)

Comment: If it doesn't support it, it doesn't support it.  You need a different one that does. You can probably get a used computer that has that functionality for a couple/few hundred dollars.  What's your question that you need help with?

Comment: @techie007 Why the hostility? I'm looking for expert advice, a second opinion, professional expertise.  If I have I posted to the wrong forum, let me know.  If I have insulted you, I apologize.  There are so many tools and workarounds out there that I don't know about; I was hoping to receive good quality responses, not down votes.

Comment: No hostility here; just trying to make the comment short and to the point. If you want quality answers, you need to post a question about a specific problem.  "This computer says it doesn't support feature "X", how can I make it do "X" anyway?" Isn't really an answerable problem (IMO).  PS: I didn't down-vote you. :)

Comment: @techie007 Sorry for accusing you of the downvote.  I was a little perturbed by the immediate negative reaction to my question.  Like I said originally I am not a hardware guru.  When I have posted a question whose simple answer is 'No', I simply expect people to answer 'No'.  I find a down vote a little harsh.  I feel like Keltari understood what I was asking and offered something worth trying.  If that's the best the group can do, I can handle that.  I just wanted to ask and maybe get some ideas from others who have done this kind of thing before.  My apologies for posting a terrible ques.

Comment: Questions are automatically downvoted when they're closed as *Not a real question* or *Off topic*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slim chance, but check for BIOS updates for that machine.  Sometimes they add some functionality to onboard devices.  You *may* get lucky with better WoL support.

Also, you may get around this with a new ethernet card with WoL support.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a BIOS update.  NIC adapters that support WoL still require a MB that supports it as well.

Comment: @Keltari Thanks for the response, I'll check for BIOS updates.